# An effect function must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I implemented fetch inside a useEffect function and received the following error:
[An Effect must not return anything besides a function, which is used for cleanup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPbG1.png)

Here is the code snippet for the same:

```
const Tab1 = () => {
    const [arr, updateArr] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const myFunc = txt => {
        console.log("Hello");
        console.log(txt);
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        return fetch('http://testapi')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => updateArr(json))
            .catch((error) => console.error(error))
            .finally(() => setLoading(false));
    }, []);
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={arr.categories}
                renderItem={itemData => (
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => this.myFunc(itemData.item.cno)}
                    >
                        <View>
                            <Text>{itemData.item.cno}</Text>
                            <Text>{itemData.item.name}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                )}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.cno}
            />
        </View>
    )
}`
```

Comment: The error message is correct. You should not return the `fetch` call, but simply call it. So: `useEffect(() => { fetch(...)... }, []);`

Comment: In your code, the function of `useEffect` is returning a `Promise`... Just `remove` the return statement and the warning will go away. If the function of `useEffect` returns something, that should be a cleanup function, not a `Promise`

Comment: Please do not use images for stack trace, always paste it here as text if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `return` inside `useEffect` will make it work.

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://testapi')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => updateArr(json))
            .catch((error) => console.error(error))
            .finally(() => setLoading(false));
    }, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

exactly return has to be removed

```
const Tab1 = () => {
const [arr, updateArr] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const myFunc = txt => {
    console.log("Hello");
    console.log(txt);
}
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://testapi')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => updateArr(json))
        .catch((error) => console.error(error))
        .finally(() => setLoading(false));
}, []);
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
            data={arr.categories}
            renderItem={itemData => (
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => this.myFunc(itemData.item.cno)}
                >
                    <View>
                        <Text>{itemData.item.cno}</Text>
                        <Text>{itemData.item.name}</Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.cno}
        />
    </View>
)
```

}`

Comment: this is only an extended version of accepted answer and does not provide any new information. Please always check if the answer you are trying to post is not already there.